# Is there some way to let compojure support type conversion automatically?

Tags: clojure, type-conversion, ring, compojure

Now can use compojure this way:

```
(GET ["/uri"] [para1 para2]
   ）
```

Para1 and para2 are all of type String.

I would like to let it know the type correcttly,like this:

```
(GET ["/uri"] [^String para1 ^Integer para2]
   ）
```

It can convert para1 to be Sting and para2 to Integer.

Is there some library or good way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently possible [with only Compojure](https://github.com/weavejester/compojure/issues/87).

You could use [Prismatic schema coercion](https://github.com/Prismatic/schema#transformations-and-coercion).

```
(require '[schema.core :as s])
(require '[schema.coerce :as c])
(require '[compojure.core :refer :all])
(require '[ring.middleware.params :as rparams])

(def data {:para1 s/Str :para2 s/Int s/Any s/Any})
(def data-coercer (c/coercer data c/string-coercion-matcher ))

(def get-uri
  (GET "/uri" r
        (let [{:keys [para1 para2]}  (data-coercer (:params r))]
                 (pr-str {:k1 para1 :k2 (inc para2)}))))

(def get-uri-wrapped
  (let [keywordizer (fn [h]
                      (fn [r]
                        (h (update-in r [:params] #(clojure.walk/keywordize-keys %)))))]
    (-> get-uri keywordizer rparams/wrap-params)))
```

Here is a sample run:

```
(get-uri-wrapped {:uri "/uri" :query-string "para1=a&para2=3" :request-method :get})

{:status 200,
 :headers {"Content-Type" "text/html; charset=utf-8"},
 :body "{:k1 \"a\", :k2 4}"}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is possible as of [Compojure 1.4.0](https://github.com/weavejester/compojure/wiki/Destructuring-Syntax#parameter-coercion) using the syntax `[x :<< as-int]`